# SSH Key within Gitlab CICD

Tags: ssh, gitlab-ci

I am attempting to pull from a private Gitlab repository within a gitlab-ci.yml script.  I followed the instructions located here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/ssh_keys and in addition, the conversation on this thread: https://gist.github.com/yannhowe/5ab1501156bd84c8ac261e2c17b8e3e0

The relevant chunk of the gitlab-ci.yml is:

```
  - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )'
  - eval $(ssh-agent -s)

  - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
  - chmod 700 ~/.ssh

  - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  - chmod 700 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  - ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

I added the private key into the CICD Variable section (and tried adding a line break at the end per one of the recommendations: https://gist.github.com/yannhowe/5ab1501156bd84c8ac261e2c17b8e3e0) but to no avail.  I am constantly seeing the following with the Gitlab job output:

```
Error loading key "/root/.ssh/id_rsa": invalid format
```

Thoughts on what I am doing wrong?

BTW: I added the same id_rsa to my ssh agent through the command: ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa on my Macbook and it executed fine so I am stumped on what Docker thinks is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I was not copying:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
     ......
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```